# Prove that if $ \ (A\cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$ then $ \ A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Prove that if $ \ (A\cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$ then $ \ A = B$.

My attempt:

Let $ \ x \in A \implies x \in A \cup B \implies x\notin (A \cup B)^c \implies x \notin A^c \cup B^c$ , since $ \ (A\cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$.

Then $ \ x\notin A^c$ and $ \ x \notin B^c \implies x \in A$ and $ \ x\in B \implies x \in B$

Let $ \ x \in B \implies x \in A \cup B \implies x\notin (A \cup B)^c \implies x \notin A^c \cup B^c$ , since $ \ (A\cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$.

Then $ \ x\notin A^c$ and $ \ x \notin B^c \implies x \in A$ and $ \ x\in B \implies x \in A$

I am not quite sure if this is the correct approach to this problem.

Comment: This is fine. You could only skip proving $B\subset A$  in the details beacuse of simmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to see it, I'll look over your proof in a second.

$(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$ by DeMorgan, and similarly $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c$. So your claim is equivalent to $(A \cup B)^c = (A \cap B)^c$, which after taking complements is the same as $A \cup B = A \cap B$, which obviously implies $A = B$.

Your proof seems to work on the same idea as this above, but it seems to be a little bit jumbled. When you say $x \in A \implies x \not \in B^c$, this is actually enough, since not being in $B^c$ is the same as being in $B$. So you actually already showed that $x \in A \implies x \in B$. This shows $A \subseteq B$. But the argument is totally symmetric, so you also can infer from analogous reasoning that $B \subseteq A$, which you then also state. It's just a matter of observing that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ implies $A = B$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out this can easily be solved using De Morgan law. However, I haven't really learnt it. I am new to set theory. Other than that is my reasoning and approach correct?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Like I said, it seems that you're on the right track, but the proof could be cleaned up using the reasoning I posted here.